# How to plot the values of my agent parameter in Main Agent?

Tags: anylogic

I have a model, where I am storing the agent.starttime=time() and agent.endtime = time, and using the formula agent.processingtime = agent.endtime - agent.starttime to get the processing time of each agent. And I am collecting those sample data in a Dataset.

But since those parameters of type double are inside my agent and I am trying to call that dataset in a bar chart on MAIN using Patient.Dataset() (Patient is the name of my agent). But its returning error.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand agent hierarchy and how to navigate it. See this [help page](https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to) and study the [SC tutorial](https://anylogic.help/tutorials/gis/index.html) step by step to practice.